# Python: Removing redundant lines from script

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Context: Ive been learning Python for a few months and I'm able to write codes which do work but they normally look very ugly and contain a lot of unnecessary code. But I normally struggle to find better ways to do things because of my limited knowledge.

I would like some advice on what I can improve on the code below. FYI - it works perfectly well but I'm guessing there must be ways to improve it. I know Im repeating myself in the loops for example?

```
def getTableGroupTopMember_Test1(coordinates):
    '''
    Depending on the number of coordinates given, this function/code returns a unique coordinate. 
    '''

    mylist = coordinates

    for adc in activeDataConnections:
        if mylist.Count == 1:
            for table in adc:
                if table.Name == mylist[0]:
                    print "/"
        elif mylist.Count == 2:
            for table in adc:
                if table.Name == mylist[0]:
                    for topgroup in table.TopAxis.Groups:
                        if topgroup.Name == mylist[1]:
                            print topgroup.Address
        elif mylist.Count == 3:
            for table in adc:
                if table.Name == mylist[0]:
                    for topgroup in table.TopAxis.Groups:
                        if topgroup.Name == mylist[1]:
                            for topmember in topgroup:
                                if topmember.Name == mylist[2]:
                                    print topmember.Address
        else:
            print "your code is shit!"


getTableGroupTopMember_Test1(["Table10"])
getTableGroupTopMember_Test1(["Table10", "profile_julesage",])
getTableGroupTopMember_Test1(["Table10", "profile_julesage", "_25_to_34"])
```

Output:

```
/
/2
/2[3]
```

Thanks All!

Comment: This should be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.  The site was set up explicitly for improving working code.

Comment: Had no idea, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have loops that are duplicated. You can pull them out by putting the code I haven't written inside the functions: count1, count2, count3.

```
if mylist.Count == 1:
    func = count1
elif mylist.Count == 2:
    func = count2
elif mylist.Count == 3:
    func = count3
else
   print  "your code is shit!"
   return

 for adc in activeDataConnections:
     for table in adc:
         if table.Name == mylist[0]:
              func()
```

I'm sure you can fill in the gaps

Comment: +1 This looks a lot cleaner and still allows me to maintain each case separately rather than clumping it into one big loop with conditions everywhere. Adding new cases would be easy as well and I wouldn't have to worry too much about breaking existing cases.